# Consult the same table with filter value over partition

Tags: sql, database, select, datatable

How can i get this result. My original table:

```
   Date     | Enterprise | Indicator |   Value
2020-01-01  |     1      |     1     |    12.50
2020-01-01  |     1      |     2     |  3000.00
2020-01-01  |     1      |     3     |   100.00
2020-01-02  |     2      |     1     |    13.20
2020-01-02  |     2      |     2     |  1300.03
2020-01-02  |     2      |     3     |   140.00
2020-01-03  |     3      |     1     |    13.50
2020-01-03  |     3      |     2     |  2300.00
2020-01-03  |     3      |     3     |   200.00
```

I need to expanse the value of indicator 2 for the rest indicators respecting the date and enterprise

```
   Date     | Enterprise | Indicator |   Value   |  Result
2020-01-01  |     1      |     1     |    12.50  |  3000.00
2020-01-01  |     1      |     2     |  3000.00  |  3000.00
2020-01-01  |     1      |     3     |   100.00  |  3000.00
2020-01-02  |     2      |     1     |    13.20  |  1300.00
2020-01-02  |     2      |     2     |  1300.00  |  1300.00
2020-01-02  |     2      |     3     |   140.00  |  1300.00
2020-01-03  |     3      |     1     |    13.50  |  2300.00
2020-01-03  |     3      |     2     |  2300.00  |  2300.00
2020-01-03  |     3      |     3     |   200.00  |  2300.00
```

Greetings Comunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to expanse the value of indicator 2 for the rest indicators
> respecting the date and enterprise

You can use the analytical function partition by date and enterprise as follows:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when indicator = 2 then value end) over (partition by date, enterprise) as Result
from your_table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when indicator = 2 then value end) over (partition by date) as result
from t;
```